# Solving feature dependency in git flow branch model

Tags: git-flow

Git flow is an interesting idea and branch model to manage a big project. But, for example, I want to develop a big feature which contains some sub-features, or if two features in the model they have to depend on each other, what is the best way to manage these two features in this case?

Shall I just use one feature instead of two since they depend on each other. Or I should keep using git pull feature/other-feature to feature/this-feature to ensure the dependency is up to date.

---

And a lot of time, my team member doesn't fully test the feature and marks the features as finished too early. This unfinished feature, says feature/unfinished, will be removed and merged into develop branch. After other features merged into develop, we find out there are some bugs in feature/unfinished. In this case, shall we start a new feature to fix the bug or I revert the merge of unfinished feature and restart it. The problem of restarting a feature is that, if the later merged features actually depend on this unfinished feature and I revert the merge of unfinished feature, then the develop branch will be broken. Then what is the best practice of this case?

---

Thanks!